# Should all questions that ask for recommendations be marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

According to guidelines, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

I understand that asking for a 'good' book should be marked as off-topic, because the term 'good' is vague, imprecise, and is subject to personal interpretation. The same when asking for a 'fast' tool. However, if someone provides concrete, clear parameters, like the speed of the tool, or the size of the book, should the question be marked as off-topic too?

My point here is that a question should not be marked as off-topic only because it fits into the general category of 'recommendation questions', but only if it contains attributes of the product/book/tool which are not measurable, because this way it is impossible to decide which answer is the best (or even if an answer is correct). However, if all the parameters of the desired answer are quantifiable, then there is no place for subjectiveness: if an answer satisfies the required parameters, then it is correct, otherwise it is not. Take for example the following question:

"I am looking for a Java library for geolocation **(specific topic)**, less than 50 classes and less than 10,000 lines of code **(determined size)**,  compatible with Windows and Linux **(concrete specifications)**" - What would be wrong with that?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam - er - No you can't. Recommendation questions are off topic on Programmers as well.

Comment: Well 'I am looking for a Java library for geolocation - AFAIK, no software can geolocate itself.  It needs interfaces.

Comment: @ChrisF I knew Asking such question is off topic.I am new at Programmers and reading top posts and found some [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/756/where-can-i-find-programming-puzzles-and-challenges) like that which made me confuse.Thanks for making me clear.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam - that question is closed and clearly off topic.

Comment: questions about Software Recommendations should be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. At the same time providing the requirements like  https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information  will be important

Answer (score 6):

> However, if someone provides concrete, clear parameters, like the speed of the tool, or the size of the book, should the question be marked as off-topic too?

Yes. concrete or not, it's still off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's still asking for "recommendation for a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" regardless of the tool's size, length, color or any other parameter.

> "I am looking for a Java library for geolocation (specific topic), less than 50 classes and less than 10.000 lines of code (determined size), compatible with windows and linux (concrete specifications)" - What would be wrong with that?

It's not "wrong" to ask anything, it's just that we don't expect this kind of questions in Stack Overflow. The guidelines you quoted are pretty descriptive, nothing changed here:

"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: my point here is to understand  why a certain rule is the way it is, not that it is simply a rule and  accordingly it must be obeyed.

Comment: @LPetre Well, it's still explained in the quoted text: ".. as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"

Comment: that's why I said: when all the params of the desired product are specified, and any answer that fits within these specifications is correct, than how can this attract opinionated answers? if i ask for a book in the range [300, 500] pages, than any answer within this range is correct. where is the personal opinion here?

Comment: @LPetre It's not because of the opinionated answers. Instead of asking "Is there a tool/resource that..", it's better to describe the problem and your attempts to solve it.